# Dojo DateTextBox selectable text

Tags: javascript, date, textbox, dojo

I have a Dojo DateTextBox that per requirement will also allow a time after the date.

```
<input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" value="" dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" constraints="{datePattern:'dd MMM yyyy HHmm'}" required="false" />
```

This all works fine.  What I want to know is by default dojo has text selection disabled.  I can not highlight the text or put the cursor where I want it.  It always displays at the end of the selection and you have to use the arrow keys to move the selection.  Is there a way to make it so the datetextbox works like a text box with a calendar? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like a bug.  please file a ticket at [bugs.dojotoolkit.org](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org) and reference checkin [[24131](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/changeset/24131)]